# Handling an exception thrown from inside a dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, error-handling, ads

I'm working on a project for school in which a dll is loaded.

The dll that is loaded is a bridge between my program and the Twincat System Manager which forms the bridge between the computer and a PLC via the local network.

I need to read Variables trough this whole chain from the plc to my program.

This is the way I do this:

```
Public Function adsReadReal(ByVal Variabelenaam As String) As Single
    Dim ds = New TwinCAT.Ads.AdsStream(4 * 8) ' new data stream
    Dim br = New System.IO.BinaryReader(ds) 'new binary
    Dim hVar = New Integer
    Try
        ConState(1) 
        tcclient = New TcAdsClient
        ConState(2)
        tcclient.Connect(Form1.amsAdress, 801) 'connects the tcclient to the PLC
        hVar = tcclient.CreateVariableHandle(Variabelenaam) 'creats a handle for the variable
        tcclient.Read(hVar, ds) 'read it
        ConState(5)
        Return br.ReadSingle() 'convert it from binary to readable for vb
    Catch ex As Exception
        ConState(0)
        PrintEx(ex) 'print out the exception
    finally
        tcclient.Dispose() 'make the object stop being used to prevent a lingering connection
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

Now the program loads a dll called `TwinCAT.ADS.dll` at the start of the connection module. If the Twincat system manager is running the program ends normally, but when it is not it crashes and gives me this error:

> System.DllNotFoundException was unhandled
>   Message="Kan DLL tcadsdll.dll niet laden: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden. (Uitzondering van HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
>   Source="TwinCAT.Ads"
>   TypeName=""
>   StackTrace:
>     bij TwinCAT.Ads.Internal.TcAdsDllWrapper.TcAdsDll.AdsAmsUnRegisterRouterNotification()
>     bij TwinCAT.Ads.Internal.TcAdsDllWrapper.AmsUnRegisterRouterNotification(Boolean
>   throwAdsException)
>     bij TwinCAT.Ads.Internal.TcLocalSystem.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>     bij TwinCAT.Ads.Internal.TcLocalSystem.Finalize()

which is roughly translated to:

> Cannot load DLL tcadsdll.dll: Cannot find given module. (Exception at
>   HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

This is not a dll that I have imported, so it must be from the `TwinCAT.ADS.dll`

How can I prevent the program from throwing this error at me and instead close the program peacefully? I have tried to catch all the exceptions of every dll related operation possible.

Also the source is on Bitbucket. I will make it public on request.

Some links on the official but quite unhandy Beckhoff site:

http://infosys.beckhoff.com/espanol.php?content=../content/1034/tcquickstart/html/tcquickstart_samplevisualbasicnet.htm&id=10449

**Edit:** 
Apparently using tcclient.dispose() causes the error since the finnaly statement was use instead of just after the try block

**Edit:** This currently catches the exception but it does not handle it.

```
Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MyHandler
Dim tick As Byte = 0

Sub MyHandler(sender As Object, args As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
   Dim ex As Exception = DirectCast(args.ExceptionObject, Exception)
   MsgBox("exception tick" & Str(tick))
   tick = tick + 1
   PrintEx(ex)
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
The exception isn't caught properly because in vs2008 a couple of errors occurs but the tick appears after I press F5 (continue)

When the program is run directly, I only see 1 Tick. Then windows gives an error.

Comment: Just a side note, add a finally clause after your `catch` statement.  That ensures the disposal will happen even if the program closes abnormally.

Comment: It looks to me like you are missing a dependency of the library you have imported.

Comment: @dwerner Doesn't occur when Twincat is running like it is supposed to.

Comment: Assemblies can be loaded at runtime. I don't know how you would prevent code that is not your own from trying to load this.

Comment: @dwerner is it possible to see running processes without elevation? If so, I can prevent the program from starting up any of those object that require the dll and shut it all down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try an unhandled exception handler?

```
Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MyHandler

Sub MyHandler(sender As Object, args As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
   Dim e As Exception = DirectCast(args.ExceptionObject, Exception)
   Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message)
End Sub
```

Comment: AddHandler isn't recognized here. Gives: "Syntax Error."

Comment: Make sure you're putting it in the right place: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Comment: Your error must be coming from somewhere other than where you defined this handler, otherwise it would be handled.

Comment: Okay I catch the exception after some fixes. 
But how can I solve it ?

Comment: Obviously the DLL you're calling is looking for another file. So the only way to "solve" your problem is to contact the developer of the DLL. But if my answer helped please accept it :)

Comment: my solution: just notify the user and terminate the program when the error occurs. Helped allot to catch the exception though. Thanks!